# How can I detect the drive letter of a booted USB drive from script?

Tags: deployment, vbscript, batch-file, winpe

I'm launching WinPE 2 from a bootable UFD, and I need to detect the drive letter in order to tell ImageX where to find the WIM.  However, depending on the machine I'm imaging, there are different mounted drives.

I need a way to consistently mount the UFD at, say, P: or something.  Is there a way to detect the letter of the drive from which the machine was booted, or another way to pass the location of my WIM file to a variable accessible from startnet.cmd?

Here's someone else with the same issue over at TechNet.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistadeployment/thread/3e8bb8db-a1c6-40be-b4b0-58093f4833be?prof=required#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This VBScript will show a message for each removable drive (letter:description), could be easily modified to search for a particular drive and return the letter.

```
 
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where MediaType = 11")

For Each objDisk in colDisks
    Wscript.Echo objDisk.DeviceID & objDisk.Description
Next
```

Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: This solution seems obvious now that you present it.  I bet that means it's the right answer.  Gotta wait until the morning to implement this, though.  Thanks!!

Comment: The simplest solutions are usually the best, glad I could help.

Comment: The code might look like this:
`@for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%A in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEBootRamDiskSourceDrive') do @set bootdrive=%%A`  `@echo BootDrive: %bootdrive%`

Answer (score 3):

It's a less generic solution than the others mentioned here, but there appears to be a specific way to determine which underlying volume a "RAM-drive-booted" Windows PE OS was booted from.  From the documentation on Windows PE in the [Windows Automated Installation Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2&displaylang=en):

> If you are not booting Windows
> Deployment Services, the best way to
> determine where Windows PE booted from
> is to first check for
> PEBootRamdiskSourceDrive registry key.
> If it is not present, scan the drives
> of the correct PEBootType and look for
> some kind of tag file that identifies
> the boot drive.

(The registry value in question sits under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-optimal solution. In this case, the UFD has to have a specific name, which is passed to the script which searches every possible drive letter for a match.  It's probably not practical to rely on the flash drives all having the same name.

Still hoping someone pops by with a better answer!

```
setlocal

:: Initial variables
set TMPFILE=%~dp0getdrive.tmp
set driveletters=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set MatchLabel_res=

for /L %%g in (2,1,25) do call :MatchLabel %%g %*

if not "%MatchLabel_res%"=="" echo %MatchLabel_res%

goto :END

:: Function to match a label with a drive letter. 
::
:: The first parameter is an integer from 1..26 that needs to be 
:: converted in a letter. It is easier looping on a number
:: than looping on letters.
::
:: The second parameter is the volume name passed-on to the script
:MatchLabel

:: result already found, just do nothing 
:: (necessary because there is no break for for loops)
if not "%MatchLabel_res%"=="" goto :eof

:: get the proper drive letter
call set dl=%%driveletters:~%1,1%%

:: strip-off the " in the volume name to be able to add them again further
set volname=%2
set volname=%volname:"=%

:: get the volume information on that disk
vol %dl%: > "%TMPFILE%" 2>&1

:: Drive/Volume does not exist, just quit
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :eof

set found=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims=:" %%g in (`find /C /I "%volname%" "%TMPFILE%"`) do set found=%%g

:: trick to stip any whitespaces
set /A found=%found% + 0


if not "%found%"=="0" set MatchLabel_res=%dl%:
goto :eof

:END

if exist "%TMPFILE%" del "%TMPFILE%"
endlocal
```

Comment: Using this solution raised another puzzle - the first time this script ran, it mistakenly selected the Boot volume (X:, the RAM disk) as the removable disk.  If I ran the script again, it would select the correct disk.  Just a note for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate reuben's answer in more detail, here is my batch file:

```
wpeutil UpdateBootInfo
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%l in ( `reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEBootRAMDiskSourceDrive` ) do set "PendrivePath=%%l"
set "PendriveLetter=%PendrivePath:~0,1%"
echo The boot pendrive's drive letter is %PendriveLetter%
```