# Batch file to detect if pen drive has been inserted

Tags: windows, service, batch-file

I have to write a batch file which does the following:
When a pen drive is inserted it has to copy all the *.mp3 files from the pendrive to my C drive. I thought I can achieve this by running a batch file which runs as a windows service or something, as I don't want the user to know that the mp3 files are being copied.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See ["How can I run a batch file in the background (no windows displayed)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298564/33499) on how to start a hidden batch file in the backgrond. To detect a pen drive, you can detect if a drive letter exists, see ["How do I test if a file is a directory in a Batch script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138995/33499), or [How can I detect the drive letter of a booted USB drive from script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/721755/33499)